# Overlapping Records

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I have a table called `PRODUCTS` and each `PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO` is allowed to be used only once that is product start date and return date should not clashing.

We return the products and return date is entered in `ACTUAL_RETURN_DATE` and if `ACTUAL_RETURN_DATE` is null we take `END_DATE` as return date.

You could see the records [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/427e6/1)

For example `PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO is clashing, as HP_2014 is returned on 18-Jun-2001, however HP_2012 same PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO is allotted on 18-Jun-2001.`

How can I find out using sql whether records are overlapping?

***Update 1***

There was a modification in table `PRODUCTS` to include `PRODUCT_EXTENSION_NO`.
Combination of `PRODUCT_NO,PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO and PRODUCT_EXTENSION_NO` becomes a unique row (composite primary key).

Rules are as below
Each `PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO` is allowed to be used only once that is product start date and return date should not clashing.

We return the products and return date is entered in `ACTUAL_RETURN_DATE` and if `ACTUAL_RETURN_DATE` is null we take `END_DATE` as return date.

`PRODUCT_NO` has extensions, so the `END_DATE` is extended.

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b71f5/1)

E.g. if you see the records 
`PRODUCT_NO` - `ORP76` with `PRODUCT_EXTENSION_NO` - `1` is clashing with `PRODUCT_NO`- `ORP100` with `PRODUCT_EXTENSION_NO` - `0`.

How can I find out using sql whether records are overlapping, extension of `PRODUCT_NO` is allowed though. i.e. `PRODUCT_NO` `ORP76` with extension `0` and extension 1 are basically extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `product_no` is unique, you might self-join products table and check for [overlapping dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap):

```
select *
  from PRODUCTS
 inner join products products_test
    on products.PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO 
     = products_test.PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO
   and products.start_date 
    <= nvl (products_test.ACTUAL_RETURN_DATE, products_test.end_date)
   and nvl (products.ACTUAL_RETURN_DATE, products.end_date) 
    >= products_test.start_date
   and products.product_no 
    <> products_test.product_no
```

[And here is Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/291f1/1).

**EDIT:** a version using rowid:

```
select *
  from PRODUCTS
 inner join products products_test
    on products.PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO 
     = products_test.PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO
   and products.start_date 
    <= nvl (products_test.ACTUAL_RETURN_DATE, products_test.end_date)
   and nvl (products.ACTUAL_RETURN_DATE, products.end_date) 
    >= products_test.start_date
   and products.rowid
    <> products_test.rowid
```

[Second Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/291f1/2)

**UPDATE** after clarification: the idea is to get minimum and maximum range of product start and end date counting in `extended` records, and then compare two streams for range overlap removing self-references by testing product_no and product_no_registration_no.

```
with extended as
(
  select PRODUCT_NO, 
         PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO, 
         min (START_DATE) as start_date,
         max (nvl (ACTUAL_RETURN_DATE, END_DATE)) as end_date
    from products
   group by PRODUCT_NO, PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO
)
select e1.PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO,
       e1.PRODUCT_NO,
       e1.start_date,
       e1.end_date,
       e2.PRODUCT_NO "PRODUCT_NO - CLASH",
       e2.start_date "START_DATE - CLASH",
       e2.end_date "END_DATE - CLASH"
  from extended e1
 inner join extended e2
    on e1.PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO
     = e2.PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO
   and e1.start_date <= e2.end_date
   and e1.end_date >= e2.start_date
-- Remove self-references
   and not
   (
           e1.PRODUCT_NO = e2.PRODUCT_NO
       and e1.PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO 
         = e2.PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO
   )
```

[Third Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b71f5/19).

Comment: There could be instances that product_no are not unique. Thanks

Comment: @Polappan There must be a way to exclude a record from matching itself. You might use rowid to that effect ...

Comment: I will test this thoroughly as I how it is working and will get back to you. Thanks a lot Nikola.

Comment: I have modified table structure and added rules above as update 1. How can I get overlapping or clashing records? Thanks.

Comment: @Polappan I'm sorry, I don't understand the business with `PRODUCT_NO \ PRODUCT_EXTENSION_NO`. How is END_DATE extended? What does it mean `extension of product_no is allowed`?

Comment: If user wants to extend `PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO`, they extend the `END_DATE` by adding another record with `PRODUCT_EXTENSION_NO` as `1` (previous record is `0`). So `PRODUCT_NO` remains the same along with `PRODUCT_NO_REGISTRATION_NO`, only extension will be in sequence like `0,1,2` etc. I hope I made it clear, other kindly let me know. Thanks and appreciated.

Comment: @Polappan I'm sorry for the delay, I've been reluctant to try to understand the problem. I hope that this arrives on time though.

Comment: Thanks Nikola for your time and valuable input. I am testing this to see it is catching clashing records, Appreciated. Regards.

Comment: I tried to remove the `with extended as` from the query but was not successful. Is it possible to remove the `with extended as` from the query? Regards.

Comment: No, not without complete rewrite. Why would you want to remove it? You don't want to treat all extensions as one record?

Comment: No need to rewrite I will manage with this. I am still testing the results. Thanks again. Regards